# carousel selected item highlight when we click on it (using jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

i am using twitter bootstrap carousel,

when user select one item from carousel and i want to make size bigger,

for example like this :

[image]

I have html like this :

```
<ul class="thumbnails" data-bind="foreach: AchievementItem">
    <li class="span3">
        <div class="thumbnail" tabindex="1">
            <div data-bind="click: $root.GetAchievement">
                <img data-bind="attr: { src: ImageFileName, id: 'thumbnail' + Soid }" src="../Images/DefaultPhoto.png" id="thumbnail521dfe57d94eaf0900bf5355">
            </div>
            <img src="../Images/trashIcon.png" class="trash" data-bind="attr: { id: 'trash' + Soid }, click: $root.DeleteAchievement" id="trash521dfe57d94eaf0900bf5355">
        </div>
        <div class="caption">
             <h5 data-bind="attr: { title: Title, id: 'caption' + Soid }, text: Title" title="Achievement 005" id="caption521dfe57d94eaf0900bf5355">Achievement 005</h5>

        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="span3">
        <div class="thumbnail" tabindex="1">
            <div data-bind="click: $root.GetAchievement">
                <img data-bind="attr: { src: ImageFileName, id: 'thumbnail' + Soid }" src="../Images/DefaultPhoto.png" id="thumbnail521dfe56d94eaf0900bf5354">
            </div>
            <img src="../Images/trashIcon.png" class="trash" data-bind="attr: { id: 'trash' + Soid }, click: $root.DeleteAchievement" id="trash521dfe56d94eaf0900bf5354">
        </div>
        <div class="caption">
             <h5 data-bind="attr: { title: Title, id: 'caption' + Soid }, text: Title" title="Achievement 004" id="caption521dfe56d94eaf0900bf5354">Achievement 004</h5>

        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="span3">
        <div class="thumbnail" tabindex="1">
            <div data-bind="click: $root.GetAchievement">
                <img data-bind="attr: { src: ImageFileName, id: 'thumbnail' + Soid }" src="../Images/DefaultPhoto.png" id="thumbnail521dfe56d94eaf0900bf5353">
            </div>
            <img src="../Images/trashIcon.png" class="trash" data-bind="attr: { id: 'trash' + Soid }, click: $root.DeleteAchievement" id="trash521dfe56d94eaf0900bf5353">
        </div>
        <div class="caption">
             <h5 data-bind="attr: { title: Title, id: 'caption' + Soid }, text: Title" title="Achievement 003" id="caption521dfe56d94eaf0900bf5353">Achievement 003</h5>

        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

so when user click on `<li>` element i want to make that li elemeent width and hightbigger and other item as normal,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the zoom functionality, then you can use the `animate` function on your images.

```
$("img").click(function() {
    //Normalize all <li>
    $("img").animate({width: "150px", height: "50px"}, "slow");

    //Make clicked <li> larger
    $(this).animate({width:"50%", height:"50%"}, "slow");
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ud2r4/2/

Comment: i would like to add some animation for zoom! :(

Comment: Changed my answer. Next time you should specify details though, because initially you just said increase height and width, not that you wanted it to zoom.